# Opening a custom AlertDialog from ListView button click

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I am having trouble inflating my custom dialog layout from inside a button click in a **`listView`** row. It works fine when I start the dialog from a `listView` row click, but from a button inside the row click I am getting an **`Android.View.InflateException`**.

Here is my **`getView`** method from the adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.planets_row, parent, false);

        // initialize the view holder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.zodIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.zodiacIcon);
        viewHolder.planetName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.planetName);
        viewHolder.planetDegree = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.planetDegree);
        viewHolder.zodiacName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.zodiacName);
        viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.planetExplanation);
        viewHolder.openDetail = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.planetDetailsBtn);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);         

        viewHolder.openDetail.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.openDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, viewHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                 View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.dialog_details, null);
                 dialog.setView(view);

                 TextView explan = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.explanationDetail);
                 Button ok = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.ok);
                 dialog.setTitle(viewHolder.planetName.getText() + 
                         " " + viewHolder.planetDegree.getText() + " " + viewHolder.zodiacName.getText());
                 dialog.setIcon(viewHolder.zodIcon.getBackground());
                 explan.setText(descrip);
                 dialog.create();
                 ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         ((DialogInterface) dialog).dismiss();
                         return;                            
                    }
                });

                 dialog.show();

            }
        });

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    planetTitle = getPlanetName(itemsList.get(position).get("planet_id"));
    planetDeg = itemsList.get(position).get("degrees")+"\u00B0";
    zodiacName = getZodiacName(itemsList.get(position).get("zodiac_id"));
    descrip = itemsList.get(position).get("content").toString();

    viewHolder.planetName.setText(planetTitle);
    viewHolder.planetDegree.setText(" " +  planetDeg);
    viewHolder.zodiacName.setText(zodiacName);
    viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(descrip);
    viewHolder.zodIcon.setBackgroundResource(getZodiacDrawable(zodiacName));

    return convertView;
}
```

I tried other combinations such as:

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_details, null);
 dialog.setView(view);
```

**Edit**: I have included the **`print logcat`** below

Thanks in advance :)

```
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409): Process: com.astrolome, PID: 27409 
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>    
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at com.astrolome.PlanetAdapter$1.onClick(PlanetAdapter.java:71)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    ... 19 more
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "@2131361805" 
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:122)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:255)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1488)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:893)
10-20 11:50:47.431: E/AndroidRuntime(27409):    ... 22 more
```

Comment: cast your context to activity- in this format ((Activity)mContext)

Comment: I don't believe this is an issue with the context - I checked what was being passed when debugging, it is my MainFragActivity, the class that is responsible for a viewpager, specifically the PlanetFragment that sends to the adapter. The crash occurs on the line 'View view = ...',

Comment: why don't you just use one inflater instead of creating new one everytime?

Comment: I've tried that too! As in:  View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_details, null); which uses the inflater for the listRow. Same error is thrown.

Comment: i tried your code and when i set layoutInflater in my adapter constructor and use it to inflate both list row and dialog it works

Comment: @santalu I tried as per your suggestion, thank you, but the same error. please see above, I added the log.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing your activity in the adapter constructor and have it stored in a class member, like your context. Then, replace this line

```
final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

with

```
final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
```

Comment: Activity extends Context. What you're suggesting seems meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...}
```

to this:

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...}
```

I don't know if this is the only problem in your code, but this seems to be a problem.